# Providing protected API externally in addition to internal API with a class hierarchy in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I am working on a C++ library for which there is a family of abstract classes which some developers using the library, depending on their needs, will need to subclass from to interact with the rest of the library. This was thought necessary because the library itself needs to be able to instantiate and use these classes internally (sort of a plugin system). These classes have a `protected` API for interacting with the rest of the library. They also need a separate internal interface for managing the instances by providing pointers to internal structures and calling other management functions that should be transparent to the final deriving classes.

The current solution involves creating an internal base class for the management interface for each public class, and the internal library functionality just casts to that class when it needs to perform management functions.

Here is a simplified example:

```
class BaseInternal
{
public:
  void doSomething();
};

class BaseComponent
{
public:
  BaseComponent();
  virtual ~BaseComponent();
  void manageComponent();
  void setInternal(std::shared_ptr<BaseInternal>);
protected:
  const std::shared_ptr<const BaseInternal> getInternal() const;
  const std::shared_ptr<BaseInternal> getModInternal();
private:
  std::shared_ptr<BaseInternal> internal;
};

class Base : public BaseComponent
{
public:
  Base();
  virtual ~Base();
protected:
  // library "plugin" API
  virtual void overrideMe() = 0;
  virtual void overrideMe2() = 0;
  void foo() { getModInternal()->doSomething(); }
private:
  // Component access hidden here
  using BaseComponent::manageComponent;
  using BaseComponent::setInternal;
  using BaseComponent::getInternal;
  using BaseComponent::getModInternal;
};

class AInternal
{
public:
  void doASomething();
};

class AComponent
{
public:
  AComponent();
  virtual ~AComponent();
  void manageA();
  void setAInternal(std::shared_ptr<AInternal>);
protected:
  const std::shared_ptr<const AInternal> getAInternal() const;
  const std::shared_ptr<AInternal> getModAInternal();
private:
  std::shared_ptr<AInternal> aInternal;
};

class A : public AComponent, virtual public Base
{
public:
  A();
  virtual ~A();
protected:
  // library "plugin" API for A
  void bar() { getModAInternal()->doASomething(); BaseComponent::getModInternal()->doSomething();}
private:
  // Component access hidden here
  using AComponent::manageA;
  using AComponent::setAInternal;
  using AComponent::getAInternal;
  using AComponent::getModAInternal;
};

class BInternal
{
public:
  void doBSomething();
};

class BComponent
{
public:
  BComponent();
  virtual ~BComponent();
  void manageB();
  void setBInternal(std::shared_ptr<BInternal>);
protected:
  const std::shared_ptr<const BInternal> getBInternal() const;
  const std::shared_ptr<BInternal> getModBInternal();
private:
  std::shared_ptr<BInternal> bInternal;
};

// Base
class B : public BComponent, virtual public Base
{
public:
  B();
  virtual ~B();
protected:
  // library "plugin" API for B
  void baz() { getModBInternal()->doBSomething(); BaseComponent::getModInternal()->doSomething();}
private:
  // Component access hidden here
  using BComponent::manageB;
  using BComponent::setBInternal;
  using BComponent::getBInternal;
  using BComponent::getModBInternal;
};

class CInternal
{
public:
  void doCSomething();
};

class CComponent
{
public:
  CComponent();
  virtual ~CComponent();
  void manageC();
  void setCInternal(std::shared_ptr<CInternal>);
protected:
  const std::shared_ptr<const CInternal> getCInternal() const;
  const std::shared_ptr<CInternal> getModCInternal();
private:
  std::shared_ptr<CInternal> bInternal;
};

// Derived virtually from A and B since there may be future classes
// derived from C
class C : public CComponent, virtual public A, virtual public B
{
public:
  C();
  virtual ~C();
protected:
  // library "plugin" API for C
  void qux() {
    getModCInternal()->doCSomething();
    AComponent::getModAInternal()->doASomething();
    BComponent::getModBInternal()->doBSomething();
    BaseComponent::getModInternal()->doSomething();
  }
private:
  // Component access hidden here
  using CComponent::manageC;
  using CComponent::setCInternal;
  using CComponent::getCInternal;
  using CComponent::getModCInternal;
};
```

Developers utilizing this capability can then define their classes like so:

```
class MyBasePlugin : public Base
{
  // providing the implementation to the pure virtual Base functions
  void overrideMe() override {foo();}
  void overrideMe2() override {foo();}
};

class MyCPlugin : public C
{
  // providing the implementation to the pure virtual Base functions
  void overrideMe() override {qux();}
  void overrideMe2() override {bar(); baz();}
};
```

Now this allows internal code to `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` to determine how to manage the instance:

```
void manageAnInstance(std::shared_ptr<Base> instance)
{
  // If I need to access a base management function, I can static cast
  // since I know all of them are BaseComponent objects
  BaseComponent* base = static_cast<BaseComponent*>(instance.get());
  base->manageComponent();
  base->setInternal(std::make_shared<BaseInternal>());
}

void manageDerivedStuff(std::shared_ptr<Base> instance)
{
  // If I need to access a derived management function, I need to dynamic
  // cast because I don't know for sure that the instance is one of those
  // classes
  C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(instance.get());
  if(c)
  {
    CComponent* ccomp = static_cast<CComponent*>(c);
    ccomp->manageC();
    ccomp->setCInternal(std::make_shared<CInternal>());
  }

  A* a = dynamic_cast<A*>(instance.get());
  if(a)
  {
    AComponent* acomp = static_cast<AComponent*>(a);
    acomp->manageA();
    acomp->setAInternal(std::make_shared<AInternal>());
  }
}
```

There are a couple of things I really don't like about this:

- `dynamic_cast`s to determine how to manage the instance
- the management function access restriction methodology is pretty pitiful. A derived class could easily circumvent those access restrictions by calling, for example, `BaseComponent::manageComponent()`.
- the component inheritance is also just weird. It looks odd to publicly derive from a base class just to immediately hide all of those functions. I understand that the idea was to communicate a clear is-a relationship internally between the component classes and public-facing classes, but it still seems odd.

I'm sure there are probably other things that could be improved here as well.

One considered alternative was defining the management function definitions directly (privately) on the public facing classes, and then `friend`ing all of the internal classes/functions that need to use them, but that seems even worse, and much more fragile.

Is there a better way to accomplish this sort of thing?

Comment: Your question is very broad, since its not just a programming problem, but a requirements i.e. software engineering problem. Try to tackle this for us and you by also stating what you want, not what you have. Its a big amount of code you are posting which is unclear about its relevant or not. Remove irrelevant parts, or even post an additional UML diagram. There are many approaches to plugins out there.